# How to run a script file that opens localhost:3000 or ipAddress:3000 from PhantomJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, phantomjs

I use localhost:3000 for browser testing (via browser-sync in Grunt). This address or ipAddress:3000 is the only address that Browsersync uses to synchronize user interactions in multiple browsers, e.g. click, scroll etc.

My goal is to create these "interactions" in PhantomJs hence automating these interactions across the real opened browsers. (I tried imacro chrome/firefox plugin but input interaction does not sync). This is a bit like end-to-end testing except I will be able to see how the webpage behaves.

The current problem is when I try to do a simple test, i.e. capture a screen shot, it cannot access that Url address and there is not screenshot file generated. However if I were to use for example page.open(file:///d:/index.html) it works but it will not sync user interactions with other browsers.

How should I solve this?

Comment: You tried `http://localhost:3000`, right?

Comment: @Artjom B.  yes tried all combinations. Strangely after I tried it with CasperJs it worked. The only thing changed was the version of Phantom, i.e. from 1.97 to 1.8